# Exception with invoking static method in Abstract Class Using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Unable to solve this issue and desperately need help. My project is calling a dll with below class. I need to use the static method using reflection but unable to make it work due to an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
namespace Binit.Core.Database
{

public abstract class DbFormat
{
    protected static DbFormat m_internalDbFormat;
    public static DbFormat Create()
     {
          return m_internalDbFormat.internalCreate();
     }
}
}
```

Below code works

```
Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat format;
format = Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat.Create();
```

Below code using reflection fails

```
Assembly CoreDatabaseAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(APath, @"Binit.Core.Database.dll"));
Type typDbFormatClass = CoreDatabaseAssembly.GetType("Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat");
MethodInfo createFormatMethod = typDbFormatClass.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { }, null);
object objDbFormat = createFormatMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Exception:

Inner Exception Shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

InnerException null

Stacktrace

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at AB.INIT.stringToValue(String valueInUnits, String dimension, String sourceUnit, String destinationUnit)
```

m_internalDbFormat is null when i am using reflection . But when i do direct reference code it doesn't become null even though i am executing only create method. I believe it means the references are loaded using direct reference and using reflection i may need to set them explicity. it seems Binit.Core.Database.Implementation is the dll that is referenced in the project doing direct reference. so i might need to invoke this explicity . Any ideas.

Comment: are you sure you want to pass null,null to createFormatMethod. I guess the method expects some non null parameter and if your code without reflection works fine try using createFormatMethod.Invoke()

Comment: Where do you set `m_internalDbFormat`? My guess: in a static constructor which is not run when you call it through reflection (and the class was not accessed before).

Comment: I am trying hard to find it out . But there isn't a static constructor

Comment: @battech then, from where you are setting m_internalDbFormat
??

Comment: i did a detailed search to find out that Binit.Core.Database.Implementation.DbFormatImpl class is initializing the m_internalDbFormat. I had added  Binit.Core.Database.Implementation.dll to my project when i used direct reference. With reflection i am not sure why it is not automatically initialized.